# Projectile with density of a Neutron star

Tags: physics

So I was talking to a friend about the density of a neutron star and then this question hit me.   Could a projectile be made from the material of a neutron star? (artificially made or what ever)  Not asking HOW you'd get it, but first if I had some, could it exist outside of a neutron star?  Meaning, does the gravity of the neutron star keep the lattice in place? Or if I managed to to create/harvest some would it explosively decompress once it's out of the conditions that created it in the first place?

Might have a follow up question on the uses of such a thing depending on the answers here.

Comment: Well I don't know if it would expand without the huge gravity (my guess is it would), but with a teaspoon being about a billion tons I expect it will be very difficult to do anything useful with it. How would you carry or move it if it stayed in shape? https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/objects/pulsars1.html.old

Comment: @Trioxidane I was thinking more along the lines of space ship projectiles

Comment: The interior of a Neutron star is hypothesized to be mostly neutron superfluid (only near the surface is there a lattice structure). This extreme excess of neutrons is allowed due to the extreme densities which do arise from the gravitational force pulling the star inwards. Outside of the densities in neutron stars however, most of the neutrons would decay. Atomic nuclei are the only stable structures which hadrons can take at the densities found on Earth.

Comment: It's almost worse as spaceship projectiles.  Space travel is all about minimizing excess mass, so you ideally want something that gives an enormous bang for limited mass, as opposed to incredibly massive.

Answer (score 16):

It would not be stable under conditions on Earth's surface. The strong nuclear force without massive gravitational effects would cause the material to expand and change form, probably also associated with large amounts of radiation. The material might start as a small (but extremely heavy) projectile but within a tiny faction of a second it would become a vast expanding ball of superheated plasma.

The question has also been answered on the Physics stack exchange:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/what-would-happen-to-a-teaspoon-of-neutron-star-material-if-released-on-earth

Comment: "The material might start as a small (but extremely heavy) projectile but within a tiny faction of a second it would become a vast expanding ball of superheated plasma." if you can find a way to contain it until firing, that sounds like an awesome (in the classical sense as well as the modern) weapon

Comment: @Bitsplease - not unless your gun has some truly spectacular range.  It'd be akin to a nuclear hand grenade.  No one would have the endurance to be able to safely use it.

Comment: @Bitsplease you could just launch it at c-epsilon and then it wouldn't have the proper time to expand.

Comment: @jdunlop : you could make its weight small enough, that the expansion won't be the size of a nuclear bomb, but much smaller.

Comment: @alessandro : if you could launch it at such a speed, you wouldn't even need to have it made out of such an exotic material. You could make it out of styrofoam and still cause ludicrous amounts of damage.

Comment: Rob Jeffries' answer to the question on the Physics site actually does the math and concludes that even just a teaspoon full would evaporate part of the Earth (3500 times the energy of the Chicxulub impact). In order to extract it from the star and use it as a projectile (or portable energy source) one would need a stasis field around it. But then it would be awesome.

Comment: @jdunlop I'd have to imagine that any species with sufficiently advanced technology to build a containment system for such a weapon could launch it at railgun-esque velocities

Comment: @Bitsplease - railgun velocities wouldn't be enough.  Unless the containment held until impact, and unless the impact was at a distance measured in light-minutes, you'd _still_ be caught in the blast.

Comment: @jdunlop Could put the containment system in a long range missile ‍♂️

Comment: @vsz That's the joke. If you're shooting neutronium bullets because it's cool, you might as well shoot them at c-epsilon because it's even cooler and solves the containment issue.